# Only compile certain parts of my program depending on the calling assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have three assemblies. One assembly contains code that relies on the 'NETWORKING' COM service. This service is not available on some machines and I would like to only compile the code depending on the assembly that consume this assemblies.

I have two assemblies that rely on this shared assembly: One GUI and one CLI assembly.
I tried to use the `#define` preprocessor check, but this only works within the same assembly (right?).
The obvious yet time consuming choice would be to extract the code into a separate assembly.

I was wondering if there is another possibility. Just like defining symbols or something like. The CLI assembly would define the `CLI` keyword and the GUI assembly would define a keyword 'GUI'.
In the shared assembly I could then use something similiar to

```
#if CLI
using NETWORKLIST;
#endif
```

Is this somehow possible in Visual Studio / C#?

Comment: Perhaps you can use a dll plugin technology. But compiling depending on a machine is not possible unless you compile directly on the target machine...

Comment: You need to check what I'm saying.  I believe that if you put the preprocessor variable in a module that is reference by two other modules with a "using statement" that the variable will be recognized in all three modules.

Comment: Do you get an error when you have code using the COM service? If so, what error?

Answer (score 2):

Assemblies are independent, so unless you're using the same "build" each time, the short answer would be "no, you can't do that". The most appropriate approach here is to move the relevant code to another assembly - which is probably less than 3 minutes work. Alternatively: just ignore it and accept that a few extra bytes of disk space are being used unnecessarily - it won't hurt.

Comment: Just as I thought. I will move the code then.